# How to add semi-trasparent JPanel over another JComponent

Tags: java, swing

I'm trying to add a feature to an app. My goal is to cover a <del>JComponent of the</del> JFrame with a semi trasparent JPanel (it will contains a JXBusyLabel in the  middle).

Let's say we have something like this:

[image: img1]

and <del>on click</del> we'd like to have the following JPanel, but semitrasparent (which means it should allow to see, more or less, what's behinde it):

[image: img2]

<del>I tried unsuccesfully to use the glassPane.</del> Any suggestion on how to achieve this will be appreciated.
Also, i notice the background of the JXBusyLabel is different, it would be good if it works the same way as the semitrasparent jpanel background.
And the cherry on the cake would be to put the loading wheel in the middle of that jpanel.

I'll update the code below as soon as we solve each problem. 
Any suggestion on how to achieve this will be appreciated.

here is a sample code wrote on purpose:

```
public class Main {


    public static void main(String[] args)  {       
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new TestApp());      
    }

}

class TestApp implements Runnable {
    @Override
    public void run(){  
        JFrame mainWindow = new JFrame("MyFrame");
        mainWindow.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        mainWindow.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(300,300));

//      mainWindow.add(initView(),BorderLayout.CENTER);
      mainWindow.add(initLoadingPanel(),BorderLayout.CENTER);
        mainWindow.add(initButton(),BorderLayout.PAGE_END);

        mainWindow.setVisible(true);
    }

    private JPanel initView() {
        JPanel viewPort = new JPanel();
        viewPort.setLayout(new BoxLayout(viewPort, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
        viewPort.add(new JLabel("label 1"));
        viewPort.add(new JLabel("label 2"));
        viewPort.add(new JLabel("label 3"));
        viewPort.add(new JLabel("label ..."));
        viewPort.add(new JLabel("label N"));
        return viewPort;
    }

    private JPanel initLoadingPanel() {
        JPanel trasparentPanel = new JPanel();
        trasparentPanel.setOpaque(true);
        trasparentPanel.setBackground(new Color(200,230,250,100));
        trasparentPanel.add(initLoadingWheel());
        return trasparentPanel;
    }

    private Component initLoadingWheel() {
        JXBusyLabel loadingWheel = new JXBusyLabel(new Dimension(80,80));
        loadingWheel.setBackground(new Color(200,230,250,100));
        loadingWheel.setOpaque(true);
        loadingWheel.setBusy(true);
        return loadingWheel;
    }

    private JButton initButton() {
        JButton button = new JButton("Start & Stop Loading");
        button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

            }
        });
        return button;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Read the Swing tutorial on [Root Panes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/rootpane.html) and download the working
>   example.  
> [...] also check out the [Disabled Glass Pane](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/11/07/disabled-glass-pane/) for a simple
>   API. 
> You could also use a [JLayer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/jlayer.html) to decorate your panel.

As Camickr suggested, the GlassPanel works.

Here is the result:

[image: loadingWheel on a GlassPane]

The following code represent the istance of the GlassPane which have to be set as glassPane for the JFrame.

```
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class GlassPane extends JComponent implements KeyListener {

    private static Cursor WAIT_CURSOR = Cursor.getPredefinedCursor(Cursor.WAIT_CURSOR);

    private JXBusyLabel wheel;

    public GlassPane()  {
        super.setOpaque( false );
        super.setLayout( new GridBagLayout() );
        super.setBackground(initBackground());
        initWheel();
        addEventCatchers();
    }

    private void addEventCatchers() {
        addMouseListener( new MouseAdapter() {} );
        addMouseMotionListener( new MouseMotionAdapter() {} );
        addKeyListener(this);
        setFocusTraversalKeysEnabled(false);        
    }

    private Color initBackground() {
        Color base = UIManager.getColor("inactiveCaptionBorder");
        Color background = new Color(base.getRed(), base.getGreen(), base.getBlue(), 128);
        return background;
    }

    private void initWheel() {
        wheel = new JXBusyLabel();
        add(wheel, new GridBagConstraints());
    }

    /*
     *  The component is transparent but we want to paint the background
     *  to give it the disabled look.
     */
    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g)   {
        g.setColor( getBackground() );
        g.fillRect(0, 0, getSize().width, getSize().height);
    }

    /*
     *  Make the glass pane visible, start the wheel and change the cursor to the wait cursor
     */
    public void activate(boolean toggle) {
        wheel.setVisible(toggle);
        wheel.setBusy(toggle);
        super.setVisible( toggle );
        setCursor(getCursor());
        if(super.isVisible()){
            requestFocusInWindow();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Cursor getCursor(){
        Cursor cursor = this.isVisible() ? GlassPane.WAIT_CURSOR : null; 
        return cursor;
    }

    /*
    *  Implement the KeyListener to consume events
    */
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e)  {
        e.consume();
    }
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
        e.consume();
    }

    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {}

}
```

here is a main method which can be used to test the above class:

```
public class Main {

    public static GlassPane glass;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                createAndShowGUI();
            }
        });
    }

    private static void createAndShowGUI() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("GlassPaneDemo");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200,200));

        Container contentPane = frame.getContentPane();
        contentPane.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        contentPane.add(new JLabel("asdasda"),BorderLayout.CENTER);
        GlassPane myGlassPane = new GlassPane();
        JButton myButton =  initButton(myGlassPane);

        contentPane.add(myButton,BorderLayout.PAGE_END);
        frame.setGlassPane(myGlassPane);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    private static JButton initButton(final GlassPane myGlassPane) {
        JButton button = new JButton("Start & Stop Loading");
        button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    myGlassPane.activate(!myGlassPane.isVisible());
            }
        });
        return button;
    }

}
```

Comment: if someone come here in future, they'd prefer to see the solution, not a suggestion, i ll check my own answer as "Accepted", if you want the green mark for your selfishness, feel free to get your hand dirty for the community.

Also, i won't accept my answer till all the problem are solved.

Thanks for the new thing u suggested, i ll check them and update the answer.

Comment: i didn't checked the Disabled Glass Pane, doing it now, code will be updated

Comment: i forgot to add a class, you're right, i ll add it tomorrow! 
Also, you're right for the not relation between original question and the answer but if a problem come after solving the previous one, maybe it's nice to explain it too. Tomorrow i ll try to manage everything. Time to sleep now. Yaaaahr!

Comment: @camickr everything seems to work properly. Code has been updated so everyone can check it out.
Thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: as already said in my previous comment, if i would come here with a doubt i'd check the accepted answer first, which in this case gives a solution (far better than an approach).
I wrote your name in the answer to credit you, if you want some reputation point (for some useless glory) feel free to copy paste my answer below, i ll accept it and delete mine, so you'll be happy and users can have the best answer.

Answer (score 2):

> I tried unsuccesfully to use the glassPane

Works fine for me. Read the Swing tutorial on [Root Panes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/rootpane.html) and download the working example. Post your `SSCCE` that demonstrates the problem.

You can also check out the [Disabled Glass Pane](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/11/07/disabled-glass-pane/) for a simple API. The current code only displays text, but you can easily modify the class to display an image since the code just uses a JLabel for the text.

You could also use a [JLayer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/jlayer.html) to decorate your panel.

Comment: thanks for the hints, i'll check tomorrow morning and update this post! Can you also help with the semiTrasparent stuff?